# how hide login button at login

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

Create a button called Login to log in, but once you log in, the button doesn't disappear.

How do I get this button to switch to logout

Answer (score 1):

best way to check customer session is login or not if login then shows the logout button and not logged in then show the login button.

Check below code I just get the customer session using object manager and set conditions.

try to find the template for use login HTML code and add condition there.

Template code

```
<?php
    $objectManagerlogin = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $customerSession = $objectManagerlogin->get('Magento\Customer\Model\Session');
    $baseurl = $objectManagerlogin->get('Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface')->getStore(0)->getBaseUrl();

?>
<div class="logincs">
    <?php if($customerSession->isLoggedIn()) { ?>
     <a href="<?php echo $baseurl .'customer/account/logout'; ?>"><span>Logout</span>
     <?php }else{ ?>
     <a href="<?php echo $baseurl .'customer/account/login/'; ?>">Login</a>
    <?php } ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the condition for the logged In customers and hide or change the text with a link for the button.

To check the customer is logged In or not you can use below two methods.

**Using ObjectManager**

```
<?php
    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $userContext = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\Http\Context');
    $isLoggedIn = $userContext->getValue(\Magento\Customer\Model\Context::CONTEXT_AUTH);
?>
<?php if($isLoggedIn): ?>
    <a href="<?= $this->getUrl('customer/account/logout') ?>"><?= __('Logout') ?></a>
<?php else: ?>
    <a href="<?= $this->getUrl('customer/account/login') ?>"><?= __('Login') ?></a>
<?php endif; ?>
```

**Using Dependency Injection**

You can check Customer is logged in or not by below way,
In Block file, Pass Magento\Framework\App\Http\Context as a dependency to the construct method.

> **app/code/Vendor/Module/Block/Customer.php**

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Block;
class Customer extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Http\Context $httpContext,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->httpContext = $httpContext;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    /*
     * return bool
     */
    public function getIsLogin() {
        return $this->httpContext->isLoggedIn();
    }
?>
```

And then Call **getIsLogin** function in template PHTML file.

```
$isLoggedin = $block->getIsLogin();
<?php if($isLoggedIn): ?>
    <a href="<?= $this->getUrl('customer/account/logout') ?>"><?= __('Logout') ?></a>
<?php else: ?>
    <a href="<?= $this->getUrl('customer/account/login') ?>"><?= __('Login') ?></a>
<?php endif; ?>
```